# A series of rewriterule without Last [L] Flag

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

UPDATE:
today I kind of find out what the problem is : now take a look at smaller version

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)
RewriteRule first /landingpage1.php [R,ENV=lang:hi]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)
RewriteRule second /landingpage2.php?id=%1&%{ENV:lang} [R,L]
```

my htaccess file location is /www/h/ folder 
if I type localhost/h/firstsecond, it returns localhost/landingpage1.php , pattern is not satisfied on 4th line
**but** if I type localhost/h/first/second, problem starts , it = lands on  localhost/landingpage2.php?id=localhost/landingpage1.php&hi , actually one time, just one time I do not know how, I find out during experiment that with localhost/h/first/second url , it redirected with first rewriterule line something like localhost/landingpage1.php//second , and ofcourse this way we see second line works , 
I have seen this kind of behavior with Alias "redirect" too, if there is something folder trail into your url , it adds remaining part into final redirected url along with query string.

so when localhost/h/firstsecond works fine but localhost/h/first/second does not , i know probably close to know what is going on.

ARCHIEVE:

I am trying to understand behaviour a bunch of rewriterule rules without Last flag
Consider my htaccess file location is localhost/h/ ( Applications/AMPPS/www/h )

Example 1:

```
RewriteRule anchor/(.+) /hello [R,ENV=lang:hi]
RewriteRule anchor /anchor/guess [R]
RewriteRule /hello /yes [R]
```

If I enter localhost/h/anchor/text
then what I think happen is

1. First line RewriteRule anchor/(.+) /hello [R,ENV=lang:hi] 's pattern "anchor/(.+)" matches and so it redirects to localhost/hello , but as there is no L flag, redirection to localhost/hello is on hold ,thus it goes below
2. Line second's pattern "anchor" does not match with new http:// localhost/hello so this is skipped
3. third line's pattern /hello matches with localhost/hello and it finally redirects to localhost/yes

Things seems as per I though untill I see example below 
Example 2:

```
RewriteRule foo/bar /tmp1/ [R]
RewriteRule foo/bar /tmp2/ [R]
RewriteRule (.+) /tmp3/ [R]
RewriteRule (.+) /tmp4/ [R]
RewriteRule hello /tmp6/ [R]
RewriteRule bar /tmp7/ [R]
RewriteRule hello /tmp8/ [R]
RewriteRule tmp7/ /tmp5/ [R]
```

same htaccess file location, I hit url localhost/h/foo/bar ,
I thought this happens

 
1. first line's pattern "foo/bar" matches with url , so it redirects to http:// localhost/tmp1/ , but as there is no L , its on hold , it goes below

2. second line's pattern "foo/bar" does not match with http:// localhost/tmp1/ , so its skipped, ( if I remove all lines except first two , I see final redirects to http:// localhost/tmp1/)
3. third line's pattern match with http:// localhost/tmp1/ and turned to http:// localhost/tmp3/
4. fourth line's pattern matches, redirect to http:// localhost/tmp4/
5. fifth line's "hello" not matched redirects still is http:// localhost/tmp4/
6. and now which thing spin my mind for last 3 hrs is sixth's line "bar" matches .. and redirects to http:// localhost/tmp7/ ( remove last 2 lines to confirm ) how ?
7. seventh's does not match as expected
8. eighth line tmp7/ matches with http:// localhost/tmp7/ and then finally redirects to http:// localhost/tmp5/

now question is why 6'th line's "bar" matches and if it can match with oldest url entered (http:// localhost/foo/bar ) then why it did not match on second line of same example  and why it did not matched in second line of example 1 ?

remember all target pattern point to outside of the folder  ( in parent, www, so that they can not hit back to the htaccess file again )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a very good question with lots of details.

If you enable `RewriteLog` you will notice this is actually being caused by this line (when you request `http://localhost/h/first/second` URL):

```
add path info postfix: /landingpage1.php/second
```

[There a bug raised specifically for this issue on Apache.org.](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38642)

This happens when you omit `L` or [`DPI` (i.e. `Discard Path Info`)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi) flags from `RewriteRule`.

It will behave well if you use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)
RewriteRule first /landingpage1.php [R,DPI,ENV=lang:hi]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)
RewriteRule second /landingpage2.php?id=%1&%{ENV:lang} [R,L]
```

Comment: awesome, I did not know any flag DPI before. it works like a charm now.

Comment: I found similar thing with mod Alias 's redirect too and as we do not use any flag with so what about it then ? is it normal n default stuff with the "redirect" ?

Comment: Can you test with `RedirectMatch` also?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. first line's pattern "foo/bar" matches with url , so it redirects to http:// localhost/tmp1/ , but as there is no L , its on hold , it
>      goes below

No, that's not how it works because of the `[R]` flag, which issues a redirect. A redirect begins a new request/response cycle and any RewriteRules will start again from the beginning. The same thing will happen with or without the `[L]` flag.

Comment: but if it issue a redirect then it should issue first redirection something like http://localhost/tmp1 from very first line, and as my htaccess file is not in root folder (or Application/AMPPS/www ) but its located in Application/AMPPS/www/h , so in this case I guess it should not hit the htaccess file again. whats your opinion ?

Comment: second, if I agree with you that it issues a redirect whenever it sees a [R] regardless of L flag , with the same logic I am not getting any idea why its satisfying 7th line "RewriteRule bar /tmp7/ [R]"